# How to insert two value in one time to array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to insert two values in one array in each loop. I have tried

```
 feature_arr = [];
    $form.find( '.variations .value' ).each( function() {
                        var $radios = $( this ).find( 'input[type=radio]' );
                        var $checked_radio = $radios.filter(':checked');
                        var attribute_name = $radios.attr( 'name' );
                        feature_arr[] = attribute_name1;
                        feature_arr[] = $checked_radio.val();
                    });
```

I want array this form `["1", "Brighton_Black", "2", "Frame_Base", "3", "Matching_upholstery", "6", "Headrest", "7", "Covered"]`

But give me error this code

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] @RobertColumbia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var feature_arr = new Array(); // define the array or you can use feature_arr = []
```

and inside your condition

```
feature_arr.push(your_value_1);
feature_arr.push(your_value_2);
```

for the second part for your question in the comment try this

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">


</style>

<body>




</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var thestring = "matching_upholstery";// this is your string 
alert(toupper(thestring)); // in here we pass out string to the method/function we wrote that returns the converted output string. to see the result we use an alert here.


//this is the function that convert the first letter to upper and return the final result
function toupper(a)
{
     var stringArray = a.split('_');//split your word from '_' character.

     var firstword = stringArray[0];//get the first word
     var firstwordWithupper = firstword.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+firstword.slice(1);//convert the first letter to upper

     var secondword = stringArray[1]; // get the second word
     var secondwordWithupper = secondword.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+secondword.slice(1);//convert the first letter of second word to upper

     var finalresult = firstwordWithupper +"_"+secondwordWithupper;
     return finalresult;
    
}


</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You are an absolute star. Thank you.

Comment: yes I can , can you put this as a seperate question and let me know. I will

Comment: Thanks @redu sloved my problem

Answer (score 1):

you can also do like

```
var a = [].concat(1,2);
```

in one line. In your case inside the condition you can do like

```
feature_arr = feature_arr.concat(value1,value2)
```

or if you receive your multiple data in an array this would result the same

```
feature_arr = feature_arr.concat([value1,value2])
```

Comment: matching_upholstery i have this word and i want to convert uppercase such as Matching_Upholstery please

Comment: you can do like `var s = "matching_upholstery".split("_").map(s => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)).join("_");`

Comment: You are an absolute legend. Thank you @redu